# Django RestFramework: Serilizer.response messing out model Response

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am having an issue that I do not know how to solve. 
I am using the REST framework, in my views.py
I have a model called Response that I want to query with

```
Response.objects.all()
```

The thing is since I imported the serializer

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
```

I think that that Django is getting lost and give me an output that

```
AttributeError: type object 'Response' has no attribute 'objects'
```

Is there a way to deal with that issue without having to rename my model ?

Thx you, 
Raphael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import your model like this:

```
from app.models import Response as ResponseModel
```

And use ResponseModel throughout your view code.It is advised to change the name of the model. if it is not possible try out the above solution.

Comment: So in order to query my db now I should do ResponseModel.objects.all() ?

Comment: it worked .. I hesitate to rename the model it is kind of pain in the ass .. ;(((
anyway thx you ;)